# The work manader's work is not controlled

Tags: java, android, multithreading, android-workmanager, java-threads

I have a wok manager that I run from the Main Activity when the user logs into the application. So, I will tell you in more detail what I do in the manager: in it I start a stream in which every second there is a mining of the virtual currency of my application, that is, simply put, I just increase the variable every second.

Moving on to the problem, here's how I run the manager

```
Constraints constraints = new Constraints.Builder()
                                    .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                                    .build();

                            miningWorkRequest = new
                                    OneTimeWorkRequest.Builder(MiningManager.class)
                                    .setConstraints(constraints)
                                    .build();

                            WorkManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).enqueue(miningWorkRequest);
```

Launching the manager completely as in the documentation.

And now the manager himself is with my mining stream. Before increasing the variable, I get it every second from Firebase Realtime, and then the miningMoneyFun() method is triggered to increase it.

```
@NonNull
    @Override
    public Result doWork() {
        firebaseModel.initAll();
        RecentMethods.UserNickByUid(firebaseModel.getUser().getUid(), firebaseModel, new Callbacks.GetUserNickByUid() {
            @Override
            public void PassUserNick(String nick) {
                RecentMethods.GetActiveMiner(nick, firebaseModel, new Callbacks.GetActiveMiners() {
                    @Override
                    public void GetActiveMiners(ArrayList<Miner> activeMinersFromBase) {
                        if(activeMinersFromBase.size()>0){
                            Thread thread = new Thread()
                            {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    try {
                                        RecentMethods.UserNickByUid(firebaseModel.getUser().getUid(), firebaseModel, new Callbacks.GetUserNickByUid() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void PassUserNick(String nick) {
                                                RecentMethods.GetTodayMining(nick, firebaseModel, new Callbacks.GetTodayMining() {
                                                    @Override
                                                    public void GetTodayMining(double todayMiningFromBase) {
                                                        todayMining=todayMiningFromBase;
                                                    }
                                                });
                                            }
                                        });
                                        while(true) {
                                            Thread.sleep(1000);
                                            miningMoneyFun();
                                            Log.d("#####", "go  "+ todayMining);
                                        }
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                    }
                                }
                            };

                            thread.start();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return Result.success();
```

What specifically does not suit me, I see from the log that the thread can be executed 5, 10 or even 15 times per second. I thought it was a thread, but when I commented it out and put the log in the DoWork() method, the log also appeared many times per second. I want the DoWork() method to run once, and then the thread itself functions every second and as expected. I saw 2 similar questions on StackOverflow, but none had clear answers, please help and sorry for the English

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that it is only one worker?

Please check like this the number of active works:

https://developer.android.com/studio/inspect/task#view-workers

Also, you should be using unique work to be sure that there are no multiple workers:

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/how-to/managing-work#unique-work

EDITED:

I am more confused by your comment. Please provide screenshots and the code the enqueue the work. At the moment you don't use periodic and unique.

Please note that you can have only 1 work in the inspector, but you can see a big list of all the executions of it.

Also, are you sure about the id? Do you generate it or it is static. It should not be possible to have multiple works when it is unique.

What flag do you use? KEEP?

**Also now I saw your code in the Worker. I don't see how you block the doWork() to finish. I think you return Success, but at the same time, you have another Thread running with nothing to prevent the app to be killed.**

Comment: I just logged into the app and opened the background tast inspector. I saw my manager called and queued 158 times there. but since I have already used a lot of data from my database, yesterday I commented out the lines of the manager call. And yes I use enqueueUniquePeriodicWork(). As far as I understand from the documentation, Work Manager performs its work asynchronously. Now I'm really confused